# (tmux+vim) vim didn't clear it's screen after exiting in tmux

Tags: vim, zsh, tmux

In the tmux shell, after exiting vim, the vim screen is not cleared. I'm using zsh. It works fine without using tmux.
The same problem is also happen with screen.

I'm using vim 7.3.672, tmux 1.7, all with default configuration.

Comment: I don't understand what means "vim screen is not cleared". Can you elaborate?

Comment: The content of file is left in the screen after quitting vim. So I will not be able to see the previous commands and output. I have go into the tmux copy mode and scroll up to see that.

Answer (score 3):

Put this line in your .screenrc:

`altscreen on`

Then screen will clear the VIM content when VIM exits.

With tmux, it should work out of the box.

PS. this is my [.tmux.conf](https://github.com/jhshi/dotfiles/blob/master/_tmux.conf)， in case you find anything interesting in it.

Comment: I removed all my customized zsh, vim and tmux configurations. Even with default configurations, it just didn't work. It might be a problem of my system. It works fine on my another linux environment. Does anyone know how to debug such issue?

Comment: After I unset the TERMINFO in zsh. The vim in Tmux will clean the screen after quit. I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

Put the following line in your .zshrc, and restart terminal.

```
export TERM=xterm
```

It works for me.